# Does WebView support WebAudio API on Android Jelly Bean 4.1?

Tags: android, audio, webview

My question is simple: Does WebView support WebAudio API on Android Jelly Bean 4.1?

I've researched at [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) and on this [comparing graph](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api) but I'm dissapionted.

So can I use WebView on Android 4.1 with WebAudio API using?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not with the built-in WebView, but you can use CrossWalk project -- it's basically a WebView that is bundled with your application, so it will work even on old Android versions. The downside is that the size of your app will increase by several dozen megabytes.

See the list of Web APIs that CrossWalk supports: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/apis/web_apis.html